GORM Soft Delete - Also set UpdatedAt to match DeletedAt
We are using GORM soft delete behavior and we also want the UpdatedAt field set to match the DeletedAt field on soft delete, but it doesn't seem to do that.
Is there a way to configure it to do so, or, do we need to define a custom type with that behaviour, e.g. something like this: https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/blob/master/soft_delete.go

You could use the BeforeDelete Hook If it fits into your codebase.
